# editing database record from codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am building a site where the user can become a member and have a minimal profile. Nevertheless, in the case that this user wishes to update his records (About Me, Email, Phone Number,etc), I want to have a link "Edit Profile". Once clicked a form is loaded with input fields with values populated from database record of that user. He/she can change the values in the fields and click Save Changes, then those are committed to database.

I tried doing it several times but kept failing. Below is the code I tried to load data in form:

```
public function load_edit()
    {
        //check user logged in 
        if(($this->session->userdata('username')!=""))
        {
            $data;
            $result = $this->profileModel->load_user_editable_data($this->session->userdata('username'));
            //check user data loaded successfully
            if(isset($result))
            {
                //get the user information and store to $data array 
                foreach($result as &$value)
                {
                    $data = $value; 
                }

                $this->load->view('profile_edit', $data);
            }
        }else{
            $this->login();
        }       
    }
```

And to update record in database table:

```
public function update_edit()
    {

         $this->form_validation->set_rules('fullname', 'الاسم الكامل', 'isset|required|alpha_dash');


        if(isset($_POST))
        {
            //check user logged in 
            if(($this->session->userdata('username')!=""))
            {
                //check that there are no form validation errors
                if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
                {   
                    $data = $this->profileModel->load_user_editable_data($this->session->userdata('username'));
                    $this->load->view('profile_edit', $data);
                }else{
                    $result = $this->profileModel->update_profile($this->session->userdata('username'));
                    if($result){

                        $this->load->view('profile_edit', $result);             
                    }
                }
            }
        }else{
            $this->load->view('error');
        }   
    }
```

The main problem I faced with the execution of above code, is that somehow when I execute update_edit, it always tells me that form validation failed and even though the condition of the field is met.

Thanks for help in advance :)

Comment: you haven't declared $data as an array, so you keep overwriting the value of it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of validation rule **isset**. Try without it.

If then the problem persists, try doing print_r($_POST) in update_edit, before you check if isset($_POST). Also check if your Session variable username is present.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with one controller function and more easy:

```
public function edit($user_id = null) {

        $data['url'] = "edit/$user_id"; // URL
        $this->load->vars($data); // Load URL for FORM
        $user = $this->profileModel->get_user($user_id); // Select USER by ID

    if($this->input->post('save')) {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
        if($this->form_validation->run()) {

            $user['username'] = $this->input->post('username'); // Get new username
            $this->profileModel->edit($user); // Edit
            // redirect somewhere. Edit done!
        }
    }

    $this->load->view('content', 'profile_edit', $user);
}
```

Here is the simple Example. You can do it with Session ID, or ID with parameter (like I did).

I hope that you will understand